# Facebook push notification on my iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, notifications, push

i have developed facebook chat app for iphone using XMPP.
But the app can not get push notification from Facebook. How can i get push notification from Facebook on my application?

Comment: Could you please supply some more information, what are your goals? What have you tried already that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: i have only implemented chat  function using xmpp.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your app the receive the push notification for a chat from Facebook. You cant do this unless you sent the push notification. This is because push notification are send to an app (Facebook app for Facebook push notifications).

Comment: i saw other apps (TapToChat not Facebook app) that receive push notification from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than polling continuously, you should try to use Facebook's realtime updates API where applicable.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

It's only applicable for certain kinds of content, but if it covers what you need, it'll be more efficient than polling like prasanna suggests.

Basically Facebook will send a request to a URL on your server whenever an event happens.  The handler for that URL should then be responsible for sending the push notifications.

Answer (score -1):

You can't bring Facebook to send a push notification to your app, you would have to set up a web server that continuously polls Facebook for changes and then sends a push notification to the iOS device when it detects a change.